# WindowsにてExitProcessをcallするアプリケーションの特定

Tags: windows

私、親アプリケーションexeからさらにサーバーexeや
別のアプリケーションexeを起動して、親アプリケーションexeが管理
するようなシステムをVC++にて開発し運用しております。

ところがWindows8.1にて知らないうちにサーバーexeと別のアプリケーションexeが
終了してしまう現象が発生します。一度起こると何度も起きますが、
何かの拍子に全く起きなくなり、一か月ぶりにPC動かしてみるとまた再発し、
使っていると数日でまた起こらなくなります。

どうもExitProcessと同レベル(TerminateProcessではない)の関数が
他の全く関係のないアプリケーションから呼ばれていることまでは
Process Monitorを使って検討がついたのですが、それが
何のアプリケーションなのかわからず試行錯誤を繰り返しております。
WindowsもしくはPCメーカーの最初から組み込まれているexeが怪しいと
思われる段階にまでは来ているのですが、立証できません。

Gflag.exeを使ってイベントログに残す方法ですと親アプリケーションexeから
起動されるため、特定することができません。

何か確実に特定する方法をご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら、
ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

既にProcess Monitorをお使いとのことですので、当該行をダブルクリックすると詳細情報が表示されます。その中にはどのプロセスから呼び出されたものか、プロセス名の記載もあります。

これで判断できないでしょうか？

Comment: Process Monitorのログファイルを更に詳しく見た結果。ExitProcessが行われる直前にtaskhostex.exeがレジストリの読み書きを毎回行っていることが分かりました。タスクスケジューラにて手動でタスクを走らせて、どのタスクが原因か突き止めようと思います。

Comment: Windows8から追加された高速スタートアップが原因のようです。

Comment: シャットダウン後、BIOSの時間を無理矢理1ヶ月早くして、作動確認→発生　　　　PC再起動→症状改善　　　シャットダウン後、更にBIOSの時間を無理矢理1ヶ月早くして、作動確認→発生　　　高速スタートアップ無効化、シャットダウン、PC起動→症状改善　　　シャットダウン後、更にBIOSの時間を無理矢理1ヶ月早くして、作動確認→発生せず　　修正してほしいなMicrosoftさん